# What is the secret of the blue bug in Your Doodles Are Bugged?

Tags: your-doodles-are-bugged

I was playing Doodle #20, which requires "some sacrifices to be made".

While playing, I got a steam achievement - Blue Bug's Secret (Discover the secret of the blue bug).

I've been wondering what the blue bug was all about, but I have no idea what happened during the chaos of that level that was supposed to be his secret.

EDIT: After further information my guess is that it has something to do with the blue fireworks that occur when the blue bug goes into the pot of "blue honey" - my guess is that there's one of these pots in every level, though I've only checked for it in two levels.  In Suicide Mission, it's just above and right of the gap; in Skydiving, it's near the floor, to the left of the honey.  I still don't know what the purpose of it is.

**What is the secret of the Blue Bug?**

Comment: This is Steam Overwatch Alpha. Clearly you have not discovered the secret of the blue bug. The achievement will be revoked immediately. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After more playing, I discovered that if you can lead the blue bug to the pot of blue honey in every level, you unlock a bonus level.**